# how to skip placeholder value if not supplied in properties file in spring boot?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot, build.gradle

I have a spring boot application that uses gradle. I have configured gradle to inject build parameters into application.properties.

Here is my gradle snippet.

```
processResources {
    expand project.properties
}
```

In the `application.properties`, I have following values

```
service.name=${name}
service.version=${version}
```

name and version are properties of gradle that will be injected.

when I run ./gradlew bootRun or ./gradlew build, I see the application.properties file being replaced with correct values.

But, when I start the using springBoot Runner from Intellij, I get the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Controller': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.company.foo.web.Controller.version; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in string value "${version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
```

when I replace the application.properties as follow, it works in spring boot runner in intellij but the gradle build fails

```
 service.name=${name: not configured}
    service.version=${version : not configured}
```

how can I tell spring boot to ignore any missing placeholder values ?

The gradle exception with stacktrace

Exception is:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':processResources'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:241)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:214)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:207)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy file '/Users/Documents/proj/src/main/resources/application.properties' to '/Users/Documents/proj/build/resources/main/application.properties'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction$FileCopyDetailsInternalAction.processFile(FileCopyAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.processFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.visitFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:81)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.jdk7.Jdk7DirectoryWalker.walkDir(Jdk7DirectoryWalker.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.walkDir(DirectoryFileTree.java:146)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visitFrom(DirectoryFileTree.java:130)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree.visit(DirectoryFileTree.java:115)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:498)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:500)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:322)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DelegatingCopySpecInternal.walk(DelegatingCopySpecInternal.java:206)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.process(CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction.execute(FileCopyAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractCopyTask.copy(AbstractCopyTask.java:83)
    at org.gradle.language.jvm.tasks.ProcessResources.copy(ProcessResources.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:585)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:568)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: configured for class: SimpleTemplateScript1
    at SimpleTemplateScript1$_run_closure1.doCall(SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy:3)
    at SimpleTemplateScript1$_run_closure1.doCall(SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy)
    at SimpleTemplateScript1.run(SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy:3)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain$3.transform(FilterChain.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ChainingTransformer.transform(ChainingTransformer.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FilterChain.transform(FilterChain.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.open(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyFile(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:74)
    ... 97 more


BUILD FAILED
```

**EDIT**

```
public class Controller {

@Value("${service.name: not configured}")
String name;

@Value("${service.version: not configured}")
String version

//rest of code

}
```

Comment: Could you post the code with the value injection?

Comment: what do you mean? spring does the injection.

Comment: Your example is incomplete. As @Ozilophile suggested, it would be helpful to see the code where you are injecting properties into your `com.company.foo.web.Controller` class

Comment: @AndyWilkinson: I have included the `Controller` class. I think the problem is in application.properties where I have set `service.name=${name}`. `gradle processResource task` is not run when I start spring-boot as `springBootApplication`. so the place-holder value is not replaced by gradle and spring complains that `${name}` is not set.

Answer (score 2):

I solve this with Spring profiles. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

In application.properties I have

```
service.version=dev
```

In application-production.properties I have

```
service.version=${version}
```

And finally this in the build.gradle file

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('application-production.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

In dev, test and integration tests the version will be "dev", when running with the production profile it will use the build version.

This also works when running the application directly from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

I've resolved this by adding into application.yml the following:

```
${version?:unknown}
```

It also work from cli:**gradle bootRun** and also from IntelliJ and you **don't** have to call the Gradle task processResources before launching in IntelliJ or use spring profiles.

This work with Gradle ver:**4.6** and also Spring Boot ver: **2.0.1.RELEASE**.
   Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - really annoying. Best solution I have found so far is to save a run/debug configuration in IntelliJ and then go in an edit the configuration, specifying that the gradle task processResources should be executed before launch.