# system property -Dspring.profiles.active not available in spring boot test config in gradle build

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a spring boot gradle application. when I run gradle builds, I want to run against different environments.

Ex : `./gradlew clean build -Dapp.env=QA1`. In the test code, I want to check for this property and gather test data accordingly. What I observed is that property (app.env) is not available.

The build should fail since the test checks for the system property. but the build is succcessful. I also do not see println statements in console.

if you want to clone repo:

git clone https://SpringDevSeattle@bitbucket.org/SpringDevSeattle/gs-rest-service.git

Here is my test code:

**src/test/java/hello/GreetingControllerTests.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={hello.TestConfig.class,hello.AppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class GreetingControllerTests {


    @Autowired
    TestEnv testEnv;

    @Autowired
    Status status;

    private String env;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        System.out.println(status.getName());
        env=testEnv.getEnv();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_fail(){
        if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("DEV")){
            assertThat(false).isFalse();
        }
        if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("QA1")){
            System.out.println("failing the test");
            fail();
        }
    }

}
```

**src/test/java/hello/TestConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {


    @Bean
    public TestEnv testEnv(){
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        String env = properties.getProperty("app.env");
        System.out.println(env);
        if (env==null){
            env="dev";
        }
        return new TestEnv(env);
    }
}
```

**src/test/java/hello/TestEnv.java**

```
public class TestEnv {


        private String env;

        public TestEnv(String env){
            this.env=env;
        }

        public String getEnv() {
            return env;
        }

        public void setEnv(String env) {
            this.env = env;
        }
}
```

**src/main/java/hello/AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${app.version}")
    private String version;
    @Value("${app.name}")
    private String name;


    @Bean
    public Status status(){
        return new Status(name,version);
    }

}
```

My ultimate goal is to set 'spring.profiles.active' for tests based on `-Dapp.env` that gets passed. but I currently do not see the system property picked up in gradle run.

**EDIT**

even with `./gradlew clean build -Dspring.profiles.active=QA1`, I do not see it working.

The test changed accordingly to this.

```
@Autowired
Environment envi

@Before
    public void init(){
        System.out.println("*********-IN THE INIT METHOD **********"); //new line added
        System.out.println(status.getName());
        env=envi.getActiveProfiles()[0];
    }

@Test
    public void should_fail(){
        if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("DEV")){
            assertThat(false).isFalse();
        }
        if (env.equalsIgnoreCase("QA1")){
            System.out.println("failing the test");
            fail();
        }
    }
```

The build fails in either case `-Dspring.profiles.active=DEV` or `-Dspring.profiles.active=QA1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gradle executes tests in a separate JVM. Therefore, system properties specified at the command line are used in the *build* JVM and are not propagated to the testing JVM. This is done on purpose to isolate the test process from the build process. You can explicitly specify system properties specifically for the test process like so.

```
test {
    systemProperty 'key', 'value'
}
```

Alternatively you can simply pass all system properties to the test process, which will allow you to specify them on the command line via the `-D` syntax.

```
test {
    systemProperties = System.props
}
```

Comment: yes, after adding this in my build.gradle, I am seeing expected behavior. but I do not see see println on console. any idea why? `System.out.println("failing the test");` in the method `should_fail`?   thanks

Comment: you can see added a print statment `System.out.println("*********-IN THE INIT METHOD **********")` in init() method. That should execute always. but I do not see in console. where does those lines go in gradle build?

Comment: You should be able to see this in the test report located in build/reports/tests/test/index.html.

Comment: can you help with this question. it is more gradle based. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752485/how-to-skip-placeholder-value-if-not-supplied-in-properties-file-in-spring-boot