# Intellij spring boot expand processResources in gradle build file to replace properties

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

Property fields are properly replaced when building from command line using `gradle build` command, however, it's not when using `IntelliJ IDEA IDE`.

code in `build.gradle`

```
ext {
    port = 8086
}

processResources {
    filesMatching('application.properties') {
        expand(project.properties)
    }
}
```

code in `application.properties`

```
server.port = ${port}
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue ? I have the same problem, I need to run in "DEBUG"

Comment: `it's not when using IntelliJ IDEA IDE` <- Does it mean it works with other IDEs like Spring Tool Suite (Eclipse)?

Answer (score 7):

When you run a Spring Boot application in IntelliJ by clicking the "Run" button, it starts with the regular java command and no gradle tasks actually run. Therefore, the task `processResources` doesn't run.

What you want is to run your project in IntelliJ by invoking the gradle task `bootRun`. In IntelliJ's gradle tool window click your project to expand it, then expand `Tasks`, expand `application`, double-click `bootRun`.

You should now see in IntelliJ's console that your application starts just as if you ran it form command line with `gradle bootRun`.

**EDIT**

In case you like to keep the ability of clicking the run/debug button in IntelliJ, you can *delegate IDE buid/run actions to gradle* by choosing this option under Settings | Build, Exectuion, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner.

Comment: This is not possible if you click on the "Debug" button, otherwise you will lose the java in-Intellij debugging experience. Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Yes. There is another solution for that. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - really annoying. Best solution I have found so far is to save a run/debug configuration in IntelliJ and then go in an edit the configuration, specifying that the gradle task processResources should be executed before launch.

A related thread:
[how to skip placeholder value if not supplied in properties file in spring boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38752485/how-to-skip-placeholder-value-if-not-supplied-in-properties-file-in-spring-boot?rq=1)

Comment: As of IntelliJ 2017.2 and/or gradle 4 this does no longer work.
Gradle 4 creates different output directories for different languages. As a result, IntelliJ decided that the IDE internal compiler and build system will no longer use the same output directories as gradle.
It is also not possible now to customize the resources output directory in IntelliJ (if it was possible, customizing it to be the same as gradle output directory could solve the problem). See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175172#comment=27-2330350

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem too. This is what I did in intellij run configuration:

- Add a gradle task `processResources`
- Add the following as VM option in the new gradle task: `-Dorg.gradle.project.buildDir=out/production`. This will change gradle build dir to the one intellij is using.