# Get value from build.gradle in Spring Batch Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have some data in my `gradle.properties` file:

```
appVersion=1.4.31
appGroup=com.business
appName=projectName
```

I want to be able to access them in a `.java` project. I am attempting to access the variable like this:

```
@Value("${appVersion}")
private int version;
```

However, when I try to run the application from the main class, I get the following error:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'appVersion' in value "${appVersion}"
```

Which shows that it can't find the correct variable.

## Attempts at solving the problem

#### Adding a `@propertySource` Annotation

I have tried adding this to the main class
`@PropertySource(value = "file:build.gradle", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)` which was unsuccessful.

#### Making changes in `build.gradle`

I attempted the following, taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963056/getting-the-gradle-build-version-into-spring-boot) StackOverflow answer:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('application.properties'){
        expand(gradle.properties)
    }
}
```

Which was also unsuccessful.

#### [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52878109/2420327) answer below

I did what was said in this answer (I had to add an `application.properties` file) and I got this error message:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Circular placeholder reference 'appVersion' in property definitions
```

I thought that it might be getting mixed up with using the same names (appVersion = appVersion), so I changed the application.properties line to

```
version=${appVersion}
```

And then in my `.java` file, I changed the line to:

```
@Value("${version}")
private String version;
```

And got the error:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'appVersion' in value "${appVersion}"
```

Comment: how do you launch your application  : from an IDE (eclipse/IDEA )? or from gradle task (run or bootRun) ?

Comment: [This](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) might help.

Comment: I launch the project from IDEA.

Comment: `application.properties` file should have already existed. Well, unless you didn't use a boot initializer I suppose. Did you place it in `src/main/resources`?

Comment: Try running the gradle process resources task before launching your app from Idea

Comment: Yes, when hovering over appVersion in IntelliJ, the following appears: `Cannot resolve configuration property 'appVersion'...`. So, maybe something else is wrong. `build.gradle` and `gradle.propeties` are in the root of the project. `application.properties` is in `src.man.resources`. The java class is in `src.main.java.com.business`.

Comment: Did you try running `processResources` before running it in Idea? Alternatively, you can try running `bootRun` and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('application.properties'){
        expand(gradle.properties)
    }
}
```

But it seems like you forgot the other part. This just tells Gradle to process your `application.properties` file and replace any placeholders it finds. You need to also put a placeholder into your `application.properties`:

```
version=${appVersion}
```

Then your value annotation should work (but it should be a `String` not an `int`)

```
@Value("${version}")
private String version;
```

Finally, since you are launching via IDEA, you may need to make sure that `gradle:processResources` runs before your application starts so that Gradle has a chance to replace the placeholder you put in `application.properties`. You should be able to utilize the "[Before Launch Options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html#before-launch-options)" section in your run configuration to have IDEA run the `processResources` Gradle Task after the build task. This should cause the placeholder to be properly replaced every time you run the application.

---

Also, just to help with the understanding. Gradle is the build system for the application, it's not part of the application itself. Once the project is built, everything related to Gradle is irrelevant. This is why you can't just do `@Value("${appVersion}")` and have it work. The application/Spring doesn't know anything about the tool that's being used to build it (and it shouldn't). So you need to somehow, at build time, inject the Gradle project version into the application if you want access to it. There are a number of ways of accomplishing this but the resource processing method above is a pretty common approach.

Comment: I gave that a go and still have a problem (I added an explanation to my question). Thank you for the explanation about Gradle. I found it useful.