# Springboot Gradle Plugin not working with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, buildship

#### THE problem

My java project doesn't run in Eclipse when I use this springboot plugin [springboot-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin)
It throws this exception

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[2020-02-09 15:45:27.825] - 12256 GRAVE [main] --- org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter: 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Constructor in com.example.demo.VersionController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.info.BuildProperties' that could not be found.
    - Bean method 'buildProperties' in 'ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnResource did not find resource '${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}'
```

#### A sample project with the issue

A sample repository with this issue can be found here:[springboot-gradle-plugin-issue](https://github.com/EspinolaAbel/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-issue)
To see this issue you need to run this project with Eclipse (I run it with eclipse 2019-09)

#### What this project does

This java project uses gradle with this plugin [spring-boot-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin).
This project prints in console the application version declared in my build.gradle file.
In my gradle.build file I include this lines:

```
springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}
```

This lines all it does is adds a Gradle Task called '*bootBuildInfo*' into gradle and while running this task it creates this file *META-INF/build-info.properties*.
In Java, when running the App, springboot automatically loads and reads *META-INF/build-info.properties* to create a bean.

#### The problem with Eclipse

All this works when I build with gradle in a terminal and run the generated jar file, but it does not work when I run my application through Eclipse.
**It doesn't create the file *META-INF/build-info.properties* and when springboot tries to load it up throws a bean not found exception because it couldn't find the file.**

#### Workarounds found

The project will run if I do one of the followings:
- manually create META-INF/build-info.properties under src/main/resources folder
- manually create META-INF/build-info.properties under build/resources/main folder

None of this aproaches are desired because it doesn't updates build-info.properties automatically

Answer (score 3):

Gradle’s Eclipse support allows you to configure tasks that should be run when a project is synchronized or built. It requires Gradle 5.4 or later and Buildship (the Eclipse plugin that provides Gradle support) 3.1 or later.

You can configure `bootBuildInfo` to run whenever Eclipse builds the project by adding the following to `build.gradle`:

```
eclipse {
    autoBuildTasks bootBuildInfo
}
```

You can learn more about the functionality in [this blog post](https://blog.gradle.org/buildship-sync-task-exec).

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer.
autoBuildTasks executes a specified task everytime I make change to a file withing Eclipse. Thanks to this the build-info.properties is generated and updated. 
But, the problem is that this file is generated outside my classpath (here build\resources\main\META-INF\build-info.properties) and when I run the application in the IDE doesn't work.

Comment: You could either run the application in your IDE via the Gradle integration (using the `bootRun` task) or you could modify the classpath that Eclipse uses.